# Is SMB smart enough to connect to closest subnet DNS A record?

Tags: networking, dns, home-networking, smb

I am investigating sharing a NAS SMB share across two different subnets. The two subnets eventually connect over a firewall, however traffic on each subnet can directly connect to the NAS bypassing the firewall.

The NAS has the following IPs (they are also on VLANs)

```
nas-media.              3600    IN      A       192.168.30.10
nas-media.              3600    IN      A       192.168.10.9
```

If a client on `192.168.10.0/24` decides to map a drive to the `nas-media` *hostname*, is it smart enough to pick the `192.168.10.9` address in lieu of `192.168.30.10` (suppose the client is Windows 7).

For anyone wondering why, the .30. network is for utility servers and .10. is a home network. The NAS is physically connected to a layer3 switch to which all servers are connected to as well as the firewall (dhcp, WAN, et al).

---

Right now all traffic from .10. will route to the firewall, and then bounce to the current `192.168.30.10` IP for the NAS. The port is a single 1Gbps ethernet connection and I am looking at this mainly for traffic management.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly going to come down to a question of how your client OS's DNS resolver and TCP connection APIs work, not anything SMB-specific.

I doubt you can rely on the client always prefering a local subnet IP address when receiving more than one A record.

Answer (score -1):

SMB/CIFS can not talk by names between different subnets, but they can talk by IP if you would set correct routing rules between subnets. So you can access your NAS from clients as `\\ip.ip.ip.ip\share` from "*alien's*" sub network.

Comment: I think you're conflating browsing (service discovery) and name resolution, but there are ways to make both work across subnets for SMB/CIFS.

Comment: @Spiff may be i miss something, but OP want to map SMB share to drive. Since DNS record contained more than one IPs I'm pretty sure that the only reliable way to map such network drive would be possible by IP only bypassing name resolution completely. Correct me pls if I'm wrong